# Pandas drop rows that have distinct value for one column, but duplicate for all others

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas in python with criminal charges and Person IDs. Some charges are listed twice for the same ID because an individual had 2 or more counts of the same charge. Some are listed twice because it was tried once in a district court, then moved to a superior court. Grouping by individual, I'd like to identify these charges, then drop the version from the district court.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
d = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
     'Court': ['district', 'district', 'district', 'superior', 'district', 'district', 'superior', 'district', 'superior'], 
     'Charge': ['larceny', 'larceny', 'assault', 'assault', 'oui', 'larceny', 'assault', 'assault', 'assault']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    ID  Court       Charge
0   1   district    larceny
1   1   district    larceny
2   1   district    assault
3   1   superior    assault
4   2   district    oui
5   2   district    larceny
6   2   superior    assault
7   3   district    assault
8   3   superior    assault
```

I can identify duplicates by ID and Charge. But it needs to be a duplicate by ID and Charge but have a *different* value for Court.

This is the result I would like:

```
    ID  Court       Charge
0   1   district    larceny
1   1   district    larceny
2   1   superior    assault
3   2   district    oui
4   2   district    larceny
5   2   superior    assault
6   3   superior    assault
```

I can identify 'duplicate' charges using duplicated(), but am not sure how to make sure the duplicates have two different values for Court before dropping.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: To address different cases having the same `Charge`, a running number can be given as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37997710/3218693) shows:

```
# a hypothetical case_id
df["case_id"] = df.groupby(["ID", "Charge", "Court"]).cumcount() + 1
```

Then group the dataset by `["ID", "Charge", "case_id"]` and use `.max()` to get the last `Court` by alphabetical ordering ("s"uperior > "d"istrict). You don't need to create an additional label column denoting `superior=1` and `district=0`.

```
# aggreagate
df_out = df.groupby(["ID", "Charge", "case_id"]).max().reset_index()
del df_out["case_id"]

# result
df_out    
Out[45]: 
   ID   Charge     Court
0   1  assault  superior
1   1  larceny  district
2   1  larceny  district
3   2  assault  superior
4   2  larceny  district
5   2      oui  district
6   3  assault  superior
```

Comment: This eliminates a few too many -- ID 1 should still list two larceny charges, for example. Is the .agg("max") working based on alphabetic order?

Comment: Yes I took it wrong. I have revised the answer by adding a hypothetical `case_id` column grouped by `["ID", "Charge", "Court"]` to denote duplicate cases. Now the output looks correct :)

Comment: I ended up creating a dummy variable for `Superior Court` since in the real dataset, the court names have additional words that would interfere with alphabetic order. Then I used  `df["final_court_superior"] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Charge', 'counter_id'])['Superior_Court'].transform('max')` to get an indicator for whether that charge ended up in Superior court. Then, dropped any records where `final_court_superior` == True and `Superior_Court == False`.  Thanks @Bill for your help in getting to this solution!

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, if the interfering characters are not in the front, then I guess you can groupby the first 8 characters of `Court` as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259801). E.g. something like `df.groupby(["ID", "Charge", df.Court.str[:8]]).cumcount()` to obtain the hypothetical counter. :)